# Google Play Store listing experiment duration

Tags: google-play

I started store listing experiment more than two months ago.

I already got more than 10K total installs. Results look pretty stable, but the experiment won't end.

Should I end the experiment manually? Should I wait till it completes? How much time can it take?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience if the experiment is not finished by one month you should end it manually and start different experiment.

I had an experiment that continued for more than 3 years with no results

[image: screenshot1]